# The effect of sugar on rate of yeast Respiration

Tags: cellular-respiration, yeast, experiment

In my experiment, I am investigating the effect of different types of sugar on the rate of respiration of immobilized yeast (yeast trapped in calcium alginate balls). I am looking at glucose, fructose, sucrose and maltose.

Research leads me to believe that the disaccharides will perform the worst as they require enzymes to breakdown into monosaccharides and so will require more time to digest and this have a slower rate of reaction. In contrast the monosaccharides will work the best for the opposite reason.

Can anyone offer any insights into this hypothesis? Any helpful background theory that would support/discredit this.

Thank you.